# Javascript fakedirectory.

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, asp-classic

In my program the user can choose a file from their local directory, and after that selection i analyse that file(xml file) in order to discover the filenames between some specific tags. My problem is: after i get that filenames i need to search them at the same local directory path without any intervention from the user. Unfortunately, the path from the first file is something like this: /fakedirectory/file.xml. There is any way to solve this?

Im coding in asp/javascript/jquery. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just forget about that. It will never work for obvious security reasons.

The only possible way is to ask the user to provide you with the path.